# Duvida em retornar arrays em ponteiros. abaixo há o codigo que eu tentei, mas so retorna endereços

Tags: c, array, c++

Boa noite, galera. seguinte, gostaria de um help para retornar um vetor, cujo objetivo é implementar uma função que receba um vetor de inteiros V e retorne um outro vetor de inteiros alocado dinamicamente com todos os valores de V que estejam entre o valor mínimo e máximo (que também são passados como parâmetro para a função). quem puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grato.valeu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * valores_entre(int * v, int n, int max, int min){
  int i;
  int cont = 0;
  int *p;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (v[i] > min && v[i] < max){
      cont++;
      p = (int )malloc(contsizeof(int));
      p[i] = v[i];
    }
  }
  free(p);
  return p;
}

int main (void){
  int vet[] = {1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5};
  int tam = sizeof(vet)/sizeof(int);
  int * resultado = valores_entre(vet, 5, 1, 5);
  int i;
  for (i =0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d\n", resultado[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: O seu código tem alguns erros fáceis de perceber como a função 'contsizeof()' não declarada ou o fato de você liberar o ponteiro p antes de retornar a função, ou o vazamento de memória dentro do loop. Isso tudo é fácil de resolver, o que não é facil de resolver é a própria lógica da função valores_entre. Explico, ela retorna um array de inteiros, o problema é que só o array é inútil e perigoso, porque você precisa saber o tamanho do array para não acontencer o que acontece no ultimo for da função main que é o programa lendo memória fora do tamanho do array.

Comment: O vetor utilizado na entrada sempre será um vetor ordenado ?

Answer (score 0):

Pressupondo que o vetor de entrada será sempre ordenado e com um "\0"  indicando o final do vetor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* valores_entre(int* v, int min, int max)
{
  /* Encontra o tamanho do vetor (presumindo que ele termina em 0) */
  int tam = 0;
  for (int i=0; v[i]!=0; i++) {
    tam++;
  }

  /* Aloca memória para um vetor de inteiros */
  int* resultado = malloc((tam - 1) * sizeof(int));
  int* vetor = resultado;

  /* Compara e adiciona número ao vetor */
  for (int j=0; j<=tam; j++) {
    if ((v[j] > min) && (v[j] < max)) {
        *vetor = v[j];
        vetor++;
    }
  }
  *vetor = 0; /* Adiciona terminador zero */

  return resultado;
}

int main (void) {
  int vet[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
  int* resultado = valores_entre(vet, 1, 5);
  int i = 0;
  while (resultado[i] != 0) {
    printf("%d\n", resultado[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```